# Customize Expand Selection

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is the behavior of Expand/Collapse Selection customizable? I want quotes to not be selected with an expansion. Also want to use other delimiters like periods, etc.

If a file isn't saved yet Expanding doesn't stop at quotes, but instead selects the entire line. Is this how Expansion is supposed to work with unsaved files?

Comment: What is an expansion?

Comment: @Carl  Not sure why you got a down vote.  Expand Select is one of the commands for key bindings.  And it would be nice if it didn't select quotes on the first run.  So I gave the question an upvote.  Unfortunately I seriously doubt whether Expand Select can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the "Expand Select" command is customizable.  <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> It is what it is.

However there is a nice extension that may act the way you want.  Look at [Expand Region](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region).  It will progressively expand or contract the region selected.  If within a quoted portion, the first expansion will **not** select the quotes.  It expands by region though, i.e., like scope.  So it will not necessarily expand only to the end of the current line if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: That's a great extension. I'm new to VSCode and this is a life saver!